# The :checked property is not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I just started with HTML and CSS a couple days ago and I'm stuck on this problem where the image margin won't change if in the :checked field. The one out of it works and it works if it modifies .Labels margins.

There was more code but it told me I couldn't post it because my post would be mostly code.

I don't know what I'm messing up here. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

h2,
h3,
ul,
li {
  color: #888;
}

.Title {
  color: #888;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: rgb(37, 194, 186);
}

p {
  background: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 11%;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: rgb(14, 36, 60);
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

.TopNav {
  background: rgb(45, 150, 141);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.BirdPicture {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

body section h2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.Slides {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.AllImages {
  width: 300%;
  display: flex;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.Boxes input {
  display: none;
}

.Boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -3% 0px 0px 0px;
}

.Label:hover {
  background: aquamarine;
}

.Label {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #40D3Dc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 8px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .3s;
}

.Slides {
  /*running*/
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#rad1:checked~.Slides {
  /* not working */
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#rad2:checked~.Slides {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#rad3:checked~.Slides {
  margin-left: -40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Curious Things</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
  <nav class="TopNav">
    <h1><span style="color:rgb(44, 44, 44);">Wild World of Birds!</span></h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="button">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="button">
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>

      <li class="button">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="button">
        <a href="#">Help</a>
      </li>

      <li class="button">
        <a href="#">Info</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      function highlight() {
        document.header.nav.ul.li.style.background = blue;
      }
    </script>
  </nav>

  <div class="AllImages">
    <div class="Slides">
      <img class="MainImage" src="https://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Background-11.jpg" width="1280" height="800">
      <img class="MainImage" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwallup.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F05%2F10%2F338365-mountains-landscapes-nature-lone-tree-natural-scenery-pure-blue.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" width="1280" height="800">
      <img class="MainImage" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixelstalk.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F10%2FHd-desktop-free-nature-wallpaper-download.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" width="1280" height="800">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Boxes">
    <input type="radio" name="imageSlider" id="radio1" class="box1">
    <input type="radio" name="imageSlider" id="radio2" class="box2">
    <input type="radio" name="imageSlider" id="radio3" class="box3">

    <label for="radio1" class="Label" id="rad1"></label>
    <label for="radio2" class="Label" id="rad2"></label>
    <label for="radio3" class="Label" id="rad3"></label>
  </div>

</header>

<body>
  <section>
    <h3>
      <br>
      <li class="Title">The Kingfisher</li>
      <img class="BirdPicture" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/04/03/science/03TB-KINGFISHER1/03TB-KINGFISHER1-mediumSquareAt3X.jpg" width="900" height="900">
      <p class="Birds">
        <span style="color:paleturquoise;">Kingfishers</span> or <span style="color:paleturquoise;">Alcedinidae</span> are a family of small to medium-sized, brightly colored birds in the order Coraciiformes. They have a cosmopolitan distribution, with
        most species found in the tropical regions of Africa, Asia, and Oceania. The family contains <span style="color:rgb(55, 216, 208)">144 species</span> and is divided into <span style="color:rgb(118, 228, 136)">three subfamalies</span> and
        <span
          style="color:rgb(60, 212, 167)">19 genera</span>. All kingfishers have large heads, long, sharp, pointed bills, short legs, and stubby tails. Most species have bright plumage with only small differences between the sexes. Most species are tropical in distribution, and a slight
          majority are found only in forests. They consume a wide range of prey usually caught by swooping down from a perch. While kingfishers are usually thought to live near rivers and eat fish, many species live away from water and eat small invertebrates.
          Like other members of their order, they nest in cavities, usually tunnels dug into the natural or artificial banks in the ground. Some kingfishers nest in arboreal termite nests. A few species, principally insular forms, are threatened with
          <span style="color:rgb(233, 109, 93)">extinction</span>. In Britain, the word "kingfisher" normally refers to <span style="color:rgb(112, 221, 179)">the common kingfisher</span>.
      </p>
    </h3>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Although you marked one CSS rule with a comment, the same selector `#rad1:checked ~ .Slides` is listed twice: `margin-left: 0%;` and `margin-left: -20%;`. ⚠️ The 2nd might override the 1st.

Comment: Why is your HTML `<head></head><header></header<body></body>`???? The header tag is not meant to be outside the body

Comment: I'm new to this, my bad. I just started Friday.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: also fixing the second #rad1:checked to #rad2:checked didn't fix it